# What HTTP status code should I use if the resource is not in the right state?

Tags: http

Let's assume I have a resource `BlogPost`. When `/blog/publish/<BlogPostId>` is called, the blog post should be published. But if it's missing a title, it should not.

What HTTP status code should I use if the request fails because the resource is not in the right state for the requested action to be performed on it?

*(I know that using verbs in my paths is not RESTful, but I'm not trying to write a REST API.)*

Comment: Which of the ten thousand "which status code to use" discussions have you read and which applicable status codes have you found and eliminated?

Comment: I have read many of them, don't worry. I eliminated most of the options because they talk about headers not matching or missing or something, but not about the resource's state itself. If you want, I can write a list of all status codes and why I think they're not appropriate. But I don't think that's getting me closer to a solution.

Comment: It would really help if you could mention the ones that are left in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to publish an incomplete resource sounds like a client error (i.e. 4xx family), especially since repeated requests to the endpoint will still result in the same error. (i.e. the client need to do an action to rectify the error before re-attempting)

There are no hard rule regarding status codes on API responses. As long as you are documenting it well and picked up those that are logically sound, it should be good.

That being said, how about `412 Precondition Failed`? [Checking the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#page-19):

> The 412 (Precondition Failed) status code indicates that one or more conditions given in the request header fields evaluated to false when tested on the server. **This response code allows the client to place preconditions on the current resource state (its current representations and metadata) and, thus, prevent the request method from being applied if the target resource is in an unexpected state.**

Since this is for your own API, you don't need to be strictly following the RFC that link that status code to header-defined preconditions. The bolded part is relevant to your use case.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the header thing was what turned me away from most of them.

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim I just edited the answer and added a quote from the RFC, looks like the bolded part more or less matches your use case.

Comment: I've looked at 412 and that parts sounds spot-on, but the first sentence bothers me: _conditions given in the request header_.

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim That part serves as guidelines for HTTP/1.1 compliant web servers. Since RESTful APIs are leveraging HTTP for its underlying transport mechanism but not actually bound to the HTTP specs, RESTful APIs don't need to follow the spec to the letter. Think of the HTTP specs as a dictionary containing common vocabularies that the RESTful APIs can use to communicate to others. As long as the meaning of each vocabulary is communicated and understood (e.g. through documentations), the API can pick whichever vocabulary that is closest to its needs.

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim, `412` seems definitely not the way to go. This status code is used for all `If-` and `ETag` cases. What I'd do is to invert the relation. *Don't accept* the post if there's anything missing, don't create the resource. Then there won't be any problem with returning it. If it's impossible, I'd hide the resource till it's completed and go for `404`.

Comment: @Opal I should probably stress again that I'm *not* talking about an API, but about a website. The user must be able to save the resource before all data is entered. (It's a draft in that state.)